# How to generate white noise without using SignalGenerator() or another built-in function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, signal-processing, noise

I am trying to analyze frequency outputs of different signals, when it came to white noise, i'm lost. I need to create an array of numbers to stream it to the sound card. Is there any algorithm that i can follow to generate a white noise. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://qualityassignmenthelp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Gaussian-noise_How-to-Generate-.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White noise is -basically- random frequencies composed together. Therefore, something like this method works fine(normalization process is also included):

```
Random rand = new Random();
void generateWhiteNoise(float[] output, int numberOfSamples)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; i++)
            {
                output[i] = 2.0f * (Convert.ToSingle(rand.NextDouble()) - 0.5f);
            }           
        }
```